# Removing large amounts of whitespace in a SwiftUI subview

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11

[Demonstration of whitespace problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8T78.gif)

When I nest a NavigationView within a NavigationView, an enormous amount of whitespace separates the back button and the new navigation bar title. Is there something I'm doing wrong in terms of setting up my SwiftUI views?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Dashboard: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var user: User
    let courses = Course.exampleCourses()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(courses) { course in
                NavigationLink(destination: CourseView(course: course)) {
                    Text(course.name)
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Welcome, \(user.first)!")
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct CourseView: View {
    // @ObservedObject allows us to update views whenever values in course change
    @ObservedObject var course: Course
    @EnvironmentObject var user: User

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: WritingPromptView(prompt: "What is your course goal, \(user.first)?", explanationText: "This is the answer", textLocation: self.$course.goal)) {
                    Text("Course Goal")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: NotepadView(parent: self.course)) {
                    Text("Notepad")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: WritingPromptView(prompt: "<Reflection prompt goes here>", explanationText: "<How to reflect goes here>", textLocation: self.$course.reflection)) {
                    Text("Reflection")
                }

            }.navigationBarTitle(course.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a double NavigationBar. Just remove NavigationView from your CourseView. If you have Previews for CourseView, you will probably want to wrap it NavigationView there.